# Stopping FOR /F command at first line of output (Windows batch)

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command

So, I need to pull the last promote message from our Accurev stream and put it in a Jenkins variable to include in Jenkins email.  The only problem I'm having is with multiple line promote messages.  I really only want the first line of the promote message, but that's not what I'm seeing with my FOR /F command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-25 delims=;" %i in ('accurev.exe hist -s <stream> -t now.1 ^|FIND "#"') DO @echo %i
```

with multiple line promote message, I get this output:

```
 # This is a multiple line promote message
 # because my programmers need to include
 # accurate descriptions of the CRs that # they work on.
```

So, any way to have my for command stop after collecting the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with GNU grep for Windows:

```
FOR /F "delims=;" %i in ('accurev.exe hist -s <stream> -t now.1 ^|grep -m1 "#"') DO @echo %i
```

Comment: grep in a batch file is a non-answer. not even close

Answer (score -1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-25 delims=;" %i in ('accurev.exe hist -s <stream> -t now.1 ^|FIND "#"') DO @echo %i && goto:eof
```

Comment: This cannot work: 1. in command prompt you cannot use `goto`; 2. in a batch file you must use `%%i` rather than `%i`...